# Connection Error accessing postgres docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, prisma

I setup a prisma project recently and here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.31
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '4030:4466'
    environment:
      TZ: ${PRISMA_DB_TIME_ZONE}
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: postgres
            port: 5432
            user: prisma
            password: ${PRISMA_DB_PASSWORD}
            migrations: true
            rawAccess: true
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.3
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PRISMA_DB_PASSWORD}
      TZ: ${PRISMA_DB_TIME_ZONE}
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
   prisma:
   postgres:
```

I can open my prisma playground and it functions without any issue. but I can't create a direct connection to the postgre container with dbeaver.

dbeaver Error message

```
Connection reset
```

Why my connection to the database fails?

This photo will be helpful.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`postgres`** by default listens on port **5432**.

In your postgres container specification, you should expose the port **5432** not **3306**.

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.31
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '4030:4466'
    environment:
      TZ: ${PRISMA_DB_TIME_ZONE}
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: postgres
            port: 5432
            user: prisma
            password: ${PRISMA_DB_PASSWORD}
            migrations: true
            rawAccess: true
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.3
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PRISMA_DB_PASSWORD}
      TZ: ${PRISMA_DB_TIME_ZONE}
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
   prisma:
   postgres:
```

If **5432** port in your **host** is **already in use** and if you want to use **3306** instead , then you can do port forwarding like below:

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.3
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "3306:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PRISMA_DB_PASSWORD}
      TZ: ${PRISMA_DB_TIME_ZONE}
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

**UPDATE - 1**

### Reason why prisma can access postgres

**ports** section is meant only to make our services accessible in **host** level. But in the container level, If a port is open in a container, any other running container can access that port with the help of **networks or links** section.

By default, **docker-compose** will create a network per `docker-compose.yml` file and joins all the services in that file into that network.

That's the reason we could use the `<service name>` as the hostname and compose will resolve that name to the ip-address of the respective (in your case **postgres**) container.

Comment: Thank you.! database connection is working now. but how did the prisma connected to the postgre container with my docker-compose.yml settings? I was using 3306:3306 I could create new nodes and all the data manipulations through the prisma playground successfully saved to the postgres.

Comment: **ports** section is meant only to make our services accessible in **host** level. But in the container level, If a port is open in a container, any other running container can access that port with the help of **networks or links** section. By default, **docker-compose** will create a network per `docker-compose.yml` file and joins all the services in that file into that network. That's the reason we could use the `<service name>` as the hostname and compose will resolve that name to the ip-address of the respective (in your case **postgres**) container.